# How to Acces DataGridView From UserControl to another UserControl

Tags: c#

I have 2 UserControl. The name of UserControl is Training and Deviasi. Training have datagridview1. I want to access datagridview1 from UserControl Training to UserControl Deviasi

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you pass the instance of the training form to the deviasi form?

Comment: I tried make a object of Training in Deviasi. But it doesn't work

Comment: how do you open the forms? is there a main form?

Comment: i put usercontrol tu main form1

Answer (score 0):

1: Inside Training UserControl Project makes public access of datagridview1 member. (if you want to expose any column of datagridview1 make it public).compile user-control project so dll created for your project on path *projrct_name/bin/debug/project_name.dll* 
2: Inside Deviasi UserControl Project Add reference dll of UserControl Training. (References->Add References->browse->select dll of user control)
3: Inside Deviasi UserControl->Create instance of UserControl Training

```
private project_name.Training userControl1;
```

In your case your project name and user control name.
OR you add you user control in tool box and access it using design view
Reference link :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/user-control-in-C-Sharp/ 
4: Inside Deviasi UserControl Project-> InitializeComponent() function you directly put complete Training user control or access userControl1.datagridview;

Comment: how to make public acces of datagridview1?
Im newbie

Comment: Training UserControl : Training.Designer.cs file you found line private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;

Comment: I have replaced it. What's next?

Comment: Follow my steps which is written in my answer

Comment: "compile user-control project so dll created for your project on path projrct_name/bin/debug/project_name.dll "

i compile project, but noting dll on my directory.

Comment: No dll in you debug folder?

Comment: yes, nothing.
This is my debug folder : 




Accord.Math.Core.dll





Accord.Math.Core






Accord.Math.dll




Accord.Math




LBPRGBbayes




LBPRGBbayes.exe




LBPRGBbayes.pdb




LBPRGBbayes.vshost



LBPRGBbayes.vshost.exe



LBPRGBbayes.vshost.exe.manifest




MRLBPbayes(This is database)



MySql.Data.dll



System.Data.SQLite.dll

Comment: your project type should be *WindowsFormsControlLibrary* for creating usercontrol.please check it